# XQuery - wrong indexes in substring after reverse-string function use

Tags: xquery, basex, functx

Im trying to implement base64 coding in a very simple way. In my approach (lets for a second put away whether its appropriate or not) I need to reverse strings and then concate them. After that this concated string is used in substring function. Strings are joined properly but when I use substring basex seems to lose it.

Funny thing is substring works for well for all indexes starting at 8. So substring($string, 1, 8) and higher gives correct output. But everything below that is messed up. Starting with one disappeared number: substring($string, 1, 7 (and below) ) results in 6 length string.
Moreover substring can start only with 1st or 0 index. Anything greater results in empty return.

> ```
> declare variable $array := [];
>
> declare function bs:encode
>   ( $input as xs:string ) {
>     bs:integer-to-binary(string-to-codepoints($input), "", $array)
> } ;
>
> declare function bs:integer-to-binary
>   ( $input as xs:integer*, $string as xs:string, $array as array(xs:string) ) {
>     let $strings :=
>     for $i in $input
>     return
>     if ($i != 0)
>     then if ($i mod 2 = 0)
>          then  bs:integer-to-binary(xs:integer($i div 2), concat($string, 0), $array)
>          else bs:integer-to-binary(xs:integer($i div 2), concat($string, 1), $array) 
>     else if ($i <= 0) 
>     then array:append($array, $string)
>     return bs:check-if-eight($strings)
>  } ;
>
>  declare function bs:check-if-eight
>   ( $strings as item()+ ) {
>     let $fullBinary :=
>     for $string in $strings
>     return if (string-length($string) < 8)
>     then bs:check-if-eight(concat($string, 0))
>     else $string (: add as private below :)
>     return bs:concat-strings($fullBinary)
>  } ;
>
> declare function bs:concat-strings
>   ( $strings as item()+ ) {
>     let $firstStringToConcat := functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 1])
>     let $secondStringToConcat := functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 2])
>     let $thirdStringToConcat := functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 3])
>     let $concat :=
>                     concat
>                           ($firstStringToConcat, 
>                            $secondStringToConcat, 
>                            $thirdStringToConcat)
> (: this returns correct string of binary value for Cat word :)
>                            return bs:divide-into-six($concat)
>  } ;  
>
> declare function bs:divide-into-six
>    ( $binaryString as xs:string) {
>      let $sixBitString := substring($binaryString, 1, 6)
>
> (: this should return 010000 instead i get 000100 which is not even in $binaryString at all :)     
>
>      return $sixBitString
>  } ;
>
>  bs:encode("Cat")
> ```

I expect first six letters from string (010000) instead I get some random sequence I guess (00100). The whole module is meant to encode strings into base64 format but for now (the part i uploaded) should just throw first six bits for 'C'

Comment: Consider to include minimal sample input and output data (both wanted and current result) in your post to demonstrate the problem. Have you tried the code with other XQuery processors?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did upload whole module to that point. I did not try to run this with other XQuery processors. It must be done in basex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out I guess.

First of all in function concat-strings I changed concat to fn:string-join. It allowed me to pass as an argument symbol that separates joined strings.

> ```
> declare function bs:concat-strings   ( $strings as item()+ )  {
> let $firstStringToConcat := xs:string(functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 1]))
> let $secondStringToConcat := xs:string(functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 2]))
> let $thirdStringToConcat := xs:string(functx:reverse-string($strings[position() = 3]))
> let $concat :=
>                 ****fn:string-join(****
>                       ($firstStringToConcat, 
>                        $secondStringToConcat, 
>                        $thirdStringToConcat),****'X'****)
>                        return bs:divide-into-six($concat)  } ;
> ```

I saw that my input looked like this:
XXXXXXXX01000011XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01100001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01110100XXXXXXXX

Obviously it had to looping somewhere without clear for loop and as I novice to Xquery i must have been missed that. And indeed. I found it in check-if-eight function:

> ```
> >  declare function bs:check-if-eight   ( $strings as item()+ ) {
> >     **let $fullBinary :=**
> >     for $string in $strings
> >     return if (string-length($string) < 8)
> >            then bs:check-if-eight(concat($string, 0))
> >            else $string (: add as private below :)
> >     **return bs:concat-strings($fullBinary)**  } ;
> ```

Despite being above FOR keyword, $fullBinary variable was in a loop and produced empty spaces(?) and it was clearly shown when i used X as a separator. 
DISCLAIMER: I thought about this before and used functx:trim but for some reason it doesnt work like I expected. So it might not for you too if having similar issue.

At this point it was clear that let $fullBinary cannot be bided in FLWR statement at least can't trigger concat-strings function. I changed it and now it produces only string and now im trying to figure out new sequence of running whole module but I think the main problem here is solved.